# Collecting Credit Card information on Cognito Form

Tags: cognito-forms

Can we collect credit card information on an encrypted Cognito form to be processed in our office through our existing credit card service at a later date?

Answer (score 2):

I'm a developer with [Cognito Forms](https://www.cognitoforms.com/).

No, per our [Terms of Service](https://www.cognitoforms.com/terms) we do not allow for the collection of credit card data.

> You are expressly prohibited from collecting and storing credit card information in Cognito Forms, except as supported by Cognito Forms for processing online payments using secure third-party payment processors such as Stripe.  When used properly, Cognito Forms servers never process, store or transmit credit card information.

Comment: While I understand, your website is misleading.  On the following page: http://help.cognitoforms.com/encrypt-entries         it says " You must encrypt any form and protect any field that contains sensitive information, such as: Social Security numbers, Driver's license numbers, Banking information, and other personally identifiable information.There is no limit to the type or number of fields that you can protect "  This is misleading - no where on that page does it state that collecting credit card information is not allowed.  You should clarify.